# Capture a Photo without saving

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to take a photo with this code:

```
capturarFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("debugging","Has clicat al botó");
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
        }           
    });

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode == 1888 && resultCode == -1) { //-1 = TOT HA ANAT BE.
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Log.d("debugging",""+photo.getHeight());
        Log.d("debugging",""+photo.getWidth());
        ((ImageView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fotoCapturada)).setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

And this is working perfectly, as I capture the photo, it's shown in the ImageView. But I'm trying to create some sort of editable options, rotation, etc. So I don't want to save it (so gallery already cached it!!).

I've read some similar questions, and this is something that would be great to do:

- Create a folder on SDCARD
- Save temporary picture there
- Create a .nomedia file so gallery don't access it.
- Remove or save applies on the picture, and leave it on that folder.

I'm trying to update above code, to adapt it to achieve these points, but the code I find in google, always use other apis, some of them, old...

Is there any "easy" way to achieve this?

The part of creating folder and creating that file, isn't a big deal, so:

**- How can I set a saving route to the pictures I take with my App?**

Thank you.

Edit:

Okay, I found some code, but It isn't working (even I gave SD writing permissions):

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/folder/" + "filename" + ".jpg");
            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I found out how to save the picture into a URI we want:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("debugging","Has clicat al botó");

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/ImagesFolder/");
            folder.mkdirs();

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/ImagesFolder/imatge.jpg"));
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
        }
```

That's it.

Remember to give permissions to write on SDCard.

Comment: PLEASE, IF YOU ARE APPLYING THIS METHOD, CONSIDER READING THIS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14187771/1943607

Comment: this will save photo in "ImagesFolder" directory.... If you have whatsapp then upload profile pic by camera it will upload your captured image but it will not store that image on sdcard, how can we do that ?

Comment: @Jayesh you can delete the saved photo in "ImagesFolder" directory after u used it.