# Emulator crashes when capturing a photo (NullPointerException)

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm having some issues while capturing photos.

Until now, I could take pictures from camera, from emulator and from a real device, without problems. But those pictures, were saved on a default route.

I wanted to edit that route, so I could set my own.

I did it this way:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/ImagesFolder/");
            folder.mkdirs();

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/ImagesFolder/imatge.jpg"));
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
```

This is working on a real device, a Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray. It creates the folder, and saves the image there.

But the issue is on emulator. I'm afraid this will happen on other devices.

This is the logcat:

```
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=264032, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.exercise.AndroidViewPager/com.exercise.AndroidViewPager.AndroidViewPagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at com.exercise.AndroidViewPager.MyFragmentD.onActivityResult(MyFragmentD.java:52)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:152)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     ... 11 more
```

The crash:

```
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 21:35:21.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at com.exercise.AndroidViewPager.MyFragmentD.onActivityResult(MyFragmentD.java:52)
```

Comes from here:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode == 1888 && resultCode == -1) { //-1 = TOT HA ANAT BE.
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Log.d("debugging",""+photo.getHeight());
        Log.d("debugging",""+photo.getWidth());
        ((ImageView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fotoCapturada)).setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

Exactly:

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

After some research, I found out nothing clear...

Can you help me on this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an SD card configured for your emulator?

Comment: @BackpackOnHead yes, it's. Actually, I execute `mkdirs()`, and it succeeds, crashes on a further line.

Comment: try this `if( requestCode == 1888 && resultCode == -1 && data != null)`

Comment: this is working, but obviously, if data is null, there's no picture to fill the ImageView. What should I do?

Comment: This is the code atm, @BackpackOnHead: `if( requestCode == 1888 && resultCode == -1 && data!=null) { //-1 = TOT HA ANAT BE.
         Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
         Log.d("debugging",""+photo.getHeight());
         Log.d("debugging",""+photo.getWidth());
         ((ImageView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fotoCapturada)).setImageBitmap(photo);
     }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data extras method isn't working, you could try storing a field of the file or the path when the Intent is launched.

```
File resultingFile;//This will be in your class definition

File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/ImagesFolder/");
folder.mkdirs();

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
resultingFile = new File(folder.toString() + "/image.jpg");
Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(resultingFile);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
```

So when you enter onActivityResult you can test the resultCode against RESULT_OK and RESULT_CANCELED. When I use onActivityResult, I do it like this:

```
if(requestCode == 1888){
  if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){ //Called when the user saves the image
     if(resultingFile.exists(){
       Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resultingFile.getPath()); 
       ((ImageView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fotoCapturada)).setImageBitmap(photo);
     }
  }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){ //Called when the user presses back or cancels the saving of the image

  }
}
```

Comment: Uhm. This is working on emulator and on my device. BUT, the photo is not being saved to `/ImagesFolder/`. It just updates the ImageView. I found out, that it's being saved to the default route. Although, maybe i could just copy the photo from that route to my own, and delete the original. What whould you do?

Comment: And to confirm my last comment I put this to the onActivityResult: `Log.d("debugging",resultingFile.getPath());` and LogCat says: ´01-06 22:56:14.009: D/debugging(1053): /mnt/sdcard/ImagesFolderimatge.jpg´. As you can see, there's some issue with the photo name. It concatenated both strings, the folder and the file.

Comment: OK. GOT IT!! Had to add an extra slash: `resultingFile=new File(folder.toString() + "/imatge.jpg");`

Answer (score 1):

After some help, specially from @BackpackOnHead, I got it.

What did I achieve?

- Retrieve a picture from camera,
- save it on a specified folder
- save it on a specified name

This is the final code:

On declaration of the class:

```
File resultingFile;
```

When clicking the button that starts camera:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("debugging","Has clicat al botó");

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/FolderWithImages/"); //NAME OF THE FOLDER
            folder.mkdirs();

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            resultingFile=new File(folder.toString() + "/imatge.jpg"); //THIS IS THE NAME OF THE FILE
            Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(resultingFile);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
        }
```

Then on, onActivityResult:

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resultingFile.getPath());
        Log.d("debugging",resultingFile.getPath());
        ((ImageView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fotoCapturada)).setImageBitmap(photo);
```

Yay!

Why did I do it this way and not with `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` ?

Basically, because for some unknown (for me) reason, on some devices, aswel as on emulator, this .getExtras is returning null, thing that in some devices, obvioulsy, as it should, isn't returning null. This "getExtras" provided the photo. We had to use a workaround, that isn't maybe clear and clean, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File f = createImageFile();
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, f.getAbsolutePath());
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

getExtras() can return null which in your case it probably does.

Comment: yes, i think this is happening. But, `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` is retrieving whole photo. What should I do in case its Null? Is there any other way to retrieve the photo? And by the way, what does "Null returning" mean? That it couldn't take the picture at all?